# Sorting Data in Array with Angular7/firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need help with sorting data in array, I want to sort Time in my table.
My time format have HH:MM, in firebase its: {hour:07,minute:15}, and this is how i sort with hour:

```
this.array.sort((a, b) => a.data.hour- b.data.hour);
```

Evryting is ok till i face two same hours:
[image]

Is there chance to sort hours first than minutes?
Or any other idea is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first sort on `hour` and then on `minute`.

```
this.array.sort((a, b) => a.data.hour - b.data.hour || a.data.minute - b.data.minute);
```